# Удалить не используемые стили css учитываю все страницы и js

Tags: javascript, css, seo

На моём сайте более 1400 страниц, и он существует около 5 лет, над сайтом работали разные программисты, по этому очень многие стили не нужны. Как проверить всего одну страницу - это мне понятно, есть много сервисов, таких как аудит от гугл хром и т.д. Но все они узнают стили на конкретной странице, а мне надо на всех(css общий). Я использовал скрип [helium](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css), но ему нельзя доверять. Он не учитывает классы, прописаные в js, так же он не учитывает @media и псевдоэлементы. + ко всему не удобная выдача результата (просто имена классов разных цветов без тела).
Скорость загрузки сайта низкая из-за огромного .css. Я понимаю, что не будет решения по 1 клику и всё готово. Возможно кто-то сталкивался и таким и может подсказать подход, который будет реально работать?

Comment: 1400 разных шаблонов страниц с уникальными css и js?

Comment: Если у них одинаковый шаблон и используемые css файлы то можно к примеру использовать https://purifycss.online/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7drmKk4EBGc&list=PLMBnwIwFEFHe5IRtm6aKN0VBUBnuog_wp&index=4 - посмотрите этот доклад. Может поможет

Comment: В частности над страницей пациентом провести такой путь:  "сохранить страницу как" -> открыть html файл в редакторе -> в папке рядом найти необходимые стили -> ввести html и стили в соответствующие колонки и получить чистый css или же просто ввести ссылку страницы и получить чистый css =)

Comment: @Кевин мне нужно учитывать js, как минимум

Comment: Компьютер не может полностью понять какой код необходим а какой нет, но для оптимизации Js есть https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code